# MS Project Agile Showing Wrong Start/Finish Dates

Tags: agile, ms-project

Hopefully you can help provide me with insight.

So I'm new to the Agile functions of MS Project, and I have a board with sprints and tasks set up. When inspecting the dates for Start/Finish times of these tasks, the dates are all incorrect; for example, if I move a task from To Do to Complete on the Sprint Board view, see it marked as complete, and check the Task Sheet, the date says 8/5 (start of the Project Date) despite today being 8/8 and the task being created today (which shows the correct date). No matter what task or sprint I mark as complete, the date always shows the Project Start date instead of the date its being modified on. I've checked Project Information and Today's Date is set appropriately at 8/8, so I don't think that's the problem.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update Task with Actual dates like Actual start and Finish dates. if you update MSP task saying that 100% Complete, simply it will follow Planned dates as System does not understand whether task is finished different dates rather than Planned dates.

if your actual dates are different than planned dates, user has manually inputs actual dates.